# Entity Framework Core ChangeTracker.TrackGraph: how to set a collection entry to some state

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

Let's say one has this model:

```cs
public class X 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public ISet<Y> Ys { get; set;
}

public class Y
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public ISet<X> Xs { get; set; }
}
```

And one does this:

```cs
var x = new X { Id = 1, Ys = new HashSet<Y> 
{ 
    new Y { Id = 1 }
}};

dbContext.ChangeTracker.TrackGraph(x, n =>
{
     if(n.Entry.IsKeySet) 
     {
         n.Entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
     }
});

dbContext.Entry(x).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

`dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries()` will output 3 entries: `X`, `Y`, and `XY` (collection), all of them in `EntityState.Unchanged`. Also, during `ChangeTracker.TrackGraph` traversal `XY` entry isn't generated.

Thus, is there any built-in approach to add a collection entry during traversal, when one has modified the `e.InboundNavigation` so one can set it to modified?

Comment: Hey @GertArnold. You know, it's a typo, I'm talking about `TrackGraph` everywhere in my question. Fixed.